# influxDB: range makes all data disappear

Tags: influxdb-2

I'm mapping my data into a single day -- today -- so that I can see busy and quiet times of the day.

```
mapToDay = (tables=<-) => tables
  |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with
    _time: date.add(d: duration(v: string(v: 60 * date.hour(t: r._time) + date.minute(t: r._time)) + "m"), to: today())
    }))
  //|> range(start: today(), stop: date.add(d: 1d, to: today()))
```

Why does the commented out `range` make all the data disappear?

[image]

**Even more strangely...**

A subsequent call to `aggregateWindow` shifts the `_time` values forward by a day.

Comment: I think its something to do with the difference between a date stamp and a time stamp, with the range converting it to purely date format and so the timestamp goes away?

Comment: The types are given as `dateTime:RFC3339`. Is there more than one?

Comment: I think its happening when you convert it by adding a day to to the timestamp, it converts it from timestamp into data format I suspect.  Now I don't use influxdb, but I've seen similar things happen in MySQL.  One specific is when someone is trying to deal with 24 hour clock and its 11PM and it rolls over to the next day, but its not correct, because its trying to add an hour and so the clock goes back around and doesn't know it went back around, cause it only tracks 24 hours .. not anything beyond that, idk if that makes sense.

Comment: You might need to do some sort of date/time format with the variable after it adds the date to reform it to include the timestamp if it wasn't truncated during the date_add of course.

Comment: So it looks like if you have it in DateTime .. that is Date and Time Stamp which is what we want, but somewhere after its in that datatype it gets turned into just Date type , and thus the rest of the time goes MIA.